# Changed file is not picked up by docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile looking like this

```
FROM debian:bullseye-slim

RUN apt-get update; \
        apt-get install -y libssl-dev; \
        apt-get clean

COPY ./runner /runner

CMD /runner
```

I build the image like this:

```
docker build -f RunnerDockerfile -t $(RUNNER_IMG) target/release
```

Even though my executable (runner) changes, it's not picked up by Docker, i.e. Docker uses the cache.

According to my understanding of the docs, if the hash of a file in a COPY statement is changed, it should be be picked up by Docker.

Example run

```
md5sum target/release/runner
32169761853677f5f7bc03acb7bbe19b  target/release/runner
```

Then I make a change:

```
md5sum target/release/runner
0075f725ce4f2cd779706b2fb9f83218  target/release/runner
```

When rebuilding the Docker images I get this

```
docker build -f RunnerDockerfile -t "runner:latest" target/release
Sending build context to Docker daemon  513.4MB
Step 1/4 : FROM debian:bullseye-slim
 ---> f8000d381a2c
Step 2/4 : RUN apt-get update;         apt-get install -y libssl-dev;         apt-get clean
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fcd7212dd477
Step 3/4 : COPY ./runner /runner
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1a79d547a9b5
Step 4/4 : CMD /runner
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a45a0fd57dd9
Successfully built a45a0fd57dd9
Successfully tagged runner:latest
```

I.e. it's using the cache for the COPY.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?